# Trying to power 6 brushless motors from a power supply/wall

Tags: power, motor, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I'm trying to power 6 of [these motors](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/turnigy-1-8th-scale-4-pole-brushless-motor-2100kv.html) using [this ESC](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/hobbykingtm-ss-series-190-200a-2-6s-esc-opto-only.html). We don't want to buy/use LiPos for the project, it will be tethered to the wall/power supply. However, I don't know how we would go about doing that, considering if I did the math right, these motors would draw upwards of 8000 W (6 x 80 A x 16.8 V [4s]).

So how would we go about doing that (we are planning to design our own PCB to distribute the power between the 6 motors, but don't know where to start)?

Comment: If the specifications on the site are to be believed, you will only need to design a PCB to power one motor since the single 15A breaker supplying your wall outlet will only let you draw 1800W continuously.

Comment: _"We don't want to buy/use LiPos for the project"_ - what does this project do?

Comment: This does not compute for me: Voltage: 3~5s Lipoly, just how many volts is that? Hopefully you can find a better data sheet. The motor (80 Amps) is only about 2X the size of wire needed to operate it.

Comment: @BruceAbbott the project is a ducted fan hexacopter, we can't use batteries because of our school's policy.

Comment: You might want to explain to your school that the batteries are arguably the less dangerous way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

You will need a power supply rated for at least 480 A. Alternatively you could power each ESC/motor from a separate supply rated at 80 A. This might be more achievable, but would require running a separate cable between each supply and its ESC.

If the power supply is based on the ground then the cable needs to carry 480 amps. 500 amp 3/0 AWG welding cable would do the job.

The biggest problem with this setup will be voltage spikes caused by the inductance of the long cable. You will need several large low-ESR capacitors to suppress this (the capacitors on the ESCs are only enough for normal battery + ESC wiring length).

You could mount the power supply (or supplies) on the hexacopter and then use a mains cable, which would be thinner and lighter (since it would only have to carry ~45 A at 220 V) and wouldn't have the inductance problem. However the weight of the power supply would probably reduce your payload capacity more.

A PCB makes a convenient way to connect all the power components together, but the tracks may not be able to handle the current. You can supplement them with copper strips soldered onto bare tinned tracks, or jumper wires (of appropriate current rating) connected between the power input and ESC power connectors.